# MFC: multiline text with more formatting?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have a dialog app which initially has static text control on top showing program name. I want to h-v centering with multiline and different font sizes to show more information nicely (figure below). I feel pretty hard using static text. For example, centerimage doesn't work with \r\n. Is there better control or approach?

[image]

Comment: Unless you are willing to host a XAML [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel), positioning, sizing, and layout is something you'll have to write code for.

Comment: You may get better format options by using a "Rich Edit" control, set to read-only.

Comment: @AdrianMole, looks like I cannot add rich edit control to dialog app?

Comment: nvm, I miss a call to init the control

Comment: AFAIK richedit control doesn't support vertical centering of its content. Though you can vertically center the richedit control itself using [`RequestResize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/mfc/reference/cricheditctrl-class?view=vs-2019#requestresize) method to calculate the minimum height that fits its content and then move/resize the control to be centered in its parent window.

Comment: @zett42, thank you for reminding me. My initial approach is to find an rtf editor to generate the string. MS Word does allow vertical centering and it seems rtf does support that (http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm). However, when I copy the string to the control text, it doesn't work very well. Looks like too much work at this point, so I switch to HTML for the job.

Comment: You can use member functions of the rich edit control ([CRichEditCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/character-formatting-in-rich-edit-controls?view=vs-2019)) to format characters and to retrieve formatting information. For characters, you can specify typeface, size, color, and effects such as bold, italic, and protected. If you encounter difficulties, please post the code that can show the problem.

Comment: Have yo seen this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/text-object-model

Comment: @IInspectable interesting, then can we use XAML stuff in MFC too? I thought this is "only" for C# and newer languages.

Comment: @tom: The Windows Runtime is written entirely in native code, surfaced through COM. There's no CLR involved anywhere.